# Скролл страницы с формой на тач устройствах

Tags: css3, html5

Всем здравствуйте. Суть вопроса в следующем. Есть форма, которая открывается в стандартной bootstrap 4 модалке. Но она слишком длинная и не помещается в один экран моб. устройств, что в свою очередь приводит к необходимости скролла. Поскольку вокруг полей формы слишком мало места, то при старте скролла с очень большой вероятностью палец попадает на поле формы, из-за чего форму не возможно протянуть вверх или вниз. То есть, другими словами,форма скроллится, если палец попал между полей формы, а если палей попадает на поле, то форму не возможно скроллисть. Подскажите, есть ли какое-то решение? 
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Почему не скролиться? тач, тап и свайп это разные вещи, скрол работает на свайп, а форма на тап, не пойму в чем проблема?

Comment: Форма длинная, и страницу приходится тянуть, но если пальцем взялся за поле формы, то она стоит на месте и не тянется вниз.
https://www.sr69.de/ сначала жмите на иконку "пользователя", а потом на Registrierung auf der Webseite и увидите форму.

Comment: ахахахах:D вы серьёзно?)

Comment: В смысле? Я что-то не понял((